# Python 3 Tkinter : AttributeError

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, attributeerror, traceback

[AttributeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0yHO.png)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\Chapter 02\2.12.py",line 11, in <module>
  from tkinter import Tk, PhotoImage, Menu, Frame, Text, Scrollbar, IntVar,\
File "C:\Users\ediaz\.spyder-py3\tkinter.py", line 10, in <module>
  class App(tk.Frame):
AttributeError:partially initialized module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Frame' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I'm trying to run my code and I keep getting this error, so then I downloaded the source code, copy and paste, clone the repository all that and I try running the code and still get this error message even in different environments. I've created and on different editors.

Comment: Don't name your script as `tkinter.py`.  Rename it to other name.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not name the file you are writing as tkinter.py or something. That is because, when you are importing a module, it can think that you are importing from the tkinter.py module that you created rather than import from the original module. This is called Circular Import
You just need to change the name of the file.